# What significance does "NewWeb" and "Blank" configurations have in WSS site definitions

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I customize a WSS site definitions by tweaking one of the built in definitions. When examining the sts definition, I see it has a configuration "NewWeb" with ID -1, and "Blank" with ID 1. In the sps definition these are defined like this:

```
<Configuration ID="-1" Name="NewWeb"/>
<Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank">
  <ExecuteUrl Url="_layouts/[%=Web.Language%]/settings.aspx" />
</Configuration>
```

Does anyone know what significance these have? Should I include them in my custom definition, or may I safely omit them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NewWeb is web that has no template associated with it.  Essentially, simply a provisioned URL.

BlankWeb is a template that specifies no lists or libraries

Comment: These are not mentioned in the webtemp manifest. And why should a null configuration be defined in all templates? Does that make sense?

Comment: I think its because the runtime needs to be aware if whether or not a provisioned site has a template.  I think its essentially a flag.